# Zend routing, throws resource not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

Ive got a url: `http://dev.local/foodies/view?id=bluedaniel`

and ive got in my bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRoute() {
        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini', 'production');
        $router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
        $router->addConfig($config, 'resources');
    }
```

and
ive also got in my routes.ini:

```
[production]
resources.router.routes.foodies_view.route = ":foodies/:id"
resources.router.routes.foodies_view.defaults.module = "foodies"
resources.router.routes.foodies_view.defaults.controller = "view"
resources.router.routes.foodies_view.defaults.action = "index"
```

so http://dev.local/foodies/bluedaniel should work right?

I get a Resource 'foodies:bluedaniel' not found error however with this setup

**--------------- UPDATE ----------------**

Instead of the above I added the following to the application.ini file:

```
resources.router.routes.myroute.route = "foodies/:id"
resources.router.routes.myroute.defaults.module = "foodies"
resources.router.routes.myroute.defaults.controller = "view"
resources.router.routes.myroute.defaults.action = "index"
resources.router.routes.myroute.defaults.id = "\w+"
```

This method now works although I would still prefer the routes in their seperate ini file if I can help it.

Comment: in fact with this updated method, now links in the zend_navigation show as /foodies. Very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I have solved the problem, now in my bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRoutes() {
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute('userprofile', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('user/:id/', array('module' => 'foodies', 'controller' => 'view', 'action' => 'index', 'id'=>'\w+')));
}
```

The problem was that in my navigation.xml I needed to add `<route>default</route>` to every node. Zend documentation can be very very poor indeed at times.

I also needed to declare a default variable for id otherwise it wouldnt recognise it being passed.

Comment: and then in the view helper $this->url(array('module'=>'foodies', 'controller'=>'view'), 'userprofile'); to create the url in the desired format.