# Custom Routing in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I m new to Zend framework and using framework 2.0. I need certain clarification on routing in PHP Zend framework.
1) What is the role of Bootstrap.php in routing.
2) How we can user index.php for routing.
3) What code needs to be written to achieve custom routing.

Also, i have written certain code, but not getting desired output.

Bootstrap.php:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{   
    protected function _initRouter()
    {
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':userid',
                                            array('controller' => 'user',              'action'=>     'index', 'userid'=>null));
        $router->addRoute('default', $route);   
    }   
}
```

index.php

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 ini_set('display_errors', true);

 //Define Base Url
 define("BASEURL","http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/sampleapp/public/");

 // directory setup and class loading
 set_include_path('.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'library/'
     . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'application/models'
     . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'application/config'
     . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()
 );

 include ('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
 $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

 // setup controller
 $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
 $frontController->throwExceptions(true);
 $frontController->setControllerDirectory('application/controllers');

 // run!
 $frontController->dispatch();
```

I'm trying to get route values, like my url is:

```
localhost:8080/sampleapp/user/index/1.
```

How should i get 1 from route. here 1 is userid.

Comment: All code you have provided is Zend-Framework 1, therefore i will retag this for better help for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to do the following:

- on index.php you should not touch anything. Leave it as it is from Zend default when you create a project
- on *projectHomeDirectory*/application/Bootstrap.php include this:

  ```
  protected function _initRoutes()
  {
          $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
          include APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/routes.php";
  }
  ```
- create a routes.php file under *projectHomeDirectory*/application/configs/ and add there all the routes you want, for example:

  ```
  $router->addRoute('sample-module/user', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
          'user/:action/:id/',
          array('module' => 'sample', 'controller' => 'user', 'id'=>'\w+')
  ));
  ```

Of course you then need to create the UserController the User model the sample module and the views.

These are some useful links:

[Zend routing, throws resource not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466822/zend-routing-throws-resource-not-found)

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard